# Encoding value in a textbox and passing it to next page

Tags: encoding, asp-classic, textbox, xss

I have a requirement in Classic ASP, I am using a txtbox to store a numeric variable then i am passing it to next page to be passed to stored procedure.

Now i am facing XSS issues so i want to encode the value of text box on parent page and then use it on the other page. I know the stored procedure will not run after getting the encoded value but its not the issue for me.

It will be great if someone can tell me how to decode it also on the next page? But that is a secondary task.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the first page's form currently posting to the second page or is there a server.transfer/response.redirect happening?

Comment: it is passing through hidden variable

Comment: Why do think you have XSS issues?  What do you mean by encode? Do you mean you need to encrypt this value for some reason?

Comment: I thought it was a textbox, not a hidden input?

Answer (score 0):

Use Server.HTMLEncode() on the page that receives the POST request.  I don't think you want to "decode" it when displaying it on another page, that defeats the point of encoding in the first place.